# How to specify multiple columns in groupby together with streaming window operations?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm not able to specify a list of columns in the `groupBy` function along with a window operation. My current code:

```
val groupCols = List("SINR_Distribution","NE_VERSION","NE_ID","NE_NAME","cNum","EarfcnDl","datetime","circle")
val aggDFrame = dframe.groupBy(groupCols, window($"EVENT_TIME", "60 minutes")).agg(Rule_Agg)
```

Error:

> Multiple markers at this line: overloaded method value groupBy with alternatives: (col1: String,cols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset  (cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset cannot be applied to (List[String], org.apache.spark.sql.Column) overloaded method value groupBy with alternatives: (col1: String,cols: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset  (cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset cannot be applied to (List[String], org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing strings with a column in the `groupBy`. The window `window($"EVENT_TIME", "60 minutes")` is correctly interpreted as a column but the list of column names needs to be columns to match, it's not possible to mix types.

What you can do is:

```scala
val cols = groupCols.map(col) ++ Seq(window($"EVENT_TIME", "60 minutes"))
val aggDFrame = dframe.groupBy(cols: _*).agg(...)
```